# Starting a new job for only a short time

Tags: job-search

My situation: I am in a position with my current job where I would like to be looking for a new job (company has bought a pre-made system to replace our main IT system, so in March my job is going to change from being a Java developer, to configuring this new system by editing xml and scripts in a proprietary language based on Java). I have been a Java developer for about 1.5 years since graduating, so I am worried about spending such a large proportion of my work experience doing such simple work and working in a proprietary language.

The problem with looking for a new job now, is that my partner is on a contract which will run out in January and his expertise is not needed much in the city we live in (though is needed in other places), so it is quite likely that we will want to move cities in less than a year (and I will be looking for a new job either way).

Given that looking for a new job, getting it and fulfilling my one month notice period will likely take several months, I could only expect to be in a new job for an absolute maximum of 9 months.

The more general question:
What will look worse on a CV - a year of work that doesn't require much of the knowledge I have and want to continue to use in the future, or a better job that only lasts 9 months?

Context - I currently work for a reasonably large financial company (hence the ability to buy a software suite so that the programmers barely need to program any more). I would like to work in something more technical in the future as my background is technical/scientific, and would certainly not rule out small companies / start ups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your situation :

Current Notice Period : 1 month

Time available for new job : 10 months max

In effect it will be a 6-8 month scenario and its good if you don't hop just for this small period of time.

However you should be taking into account the fact that, your primary skills should be constantly refreshed or updated. Even you can take this 6-8 months gap for brushing up your skills for new interview as well as learning new technologies in the related domain which might be very useful for you in future.

Further your resume will look good as by the time you are ready to move, you will attain around 3 years experience using which you can push for a mid-senior level job rather than a fresher.

And if you are forced to change since you dont have enough relevant work at current firm or your primary skills are weakening then you can jump, but at a risk of convincing your next HR personal as to why you are looking to jump after 10 months. Even though your partner job issue is a valid reason, im not sure whether you can get to a situation where you could actually convey this.

In the end if you are really confident in your skills, then you ought to believe in that and stay with current firm for the next few months enhancing your knowledge and towards the end of this 10 month period, start applying for good firms and your chances will be very high..

All the very best in any case...Cheers..

Answer (score 2):

I would advise to get a job.

Two scenarios the way I see it, with the main factor in each: Money is money.

Scenario 1:

- You get a job for ten months,
- your partners job finishes
- you move to  another location and get another job each

End of Scenario

Scenario 2:

- you get a job for ten months,
- you enjoy your job for ten months,
- your partner in turn gets a new job within that time (maybe their job keeps them on, or  there is that dream job pops up)
  End of scenario

The point I am trying to get across is, in my personal situation, I couldn't go without a job for ten months. I would rather have to take a job and leave it when I move, than be without one caught in the middle.

Failing that:

http://www.rent-acoder.com/

Comment: I will have a job either way, my current job is not ending, just changing to be something that I like less and that will not give me the benefit of good experience any more.

Comment: Think of it this way, you are still getting experience, you might change jobs and find that your next job modifies scripts. It would be something I put on my CV. Thing I learnt early in my career, almost everything is experience.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider becoming an independent contractor, or using a recruiter to find a short-term job that will end at the same time as your partners.  Working as a contractor will let you make extra money, and you can easily inform your new employer of your plan to leave after 9 months.

If you know your job will no longer be the right fit for you, you should move on before your boss realizes this.

**Be sure your current job will be a bad fit.**

Switching jobs is generally one of the most stressful life changes in one's life.  If you know you will not be engaged after the changes in your job, then by all means find a temp job that will pay by the hour and bank the money to pay for the move.  Otherwise, consider staying put.